# Git-replace with HEAD(eclipse) by mistake

Tags: eclipse, git

I did by mistake a replace with HEAD on a file. Was the file deleted and changed with the HEAD? Can I get back the file?

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you can [restore a deleted resource with the Eclipse local history](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm): see [Eclipse local history](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm).

(resource's pop-up menu, select Restore from Local History.)
(or `Team > Show Local History`)

[image: http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/images/localHistoryView.png]

That does not depend on Git and could help restoring the original content.